# How can I generate a PDF from HTML with Arabic language (client side)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jspdf

I worked with jsPDF and vue js to achieve export pdfs, it works fine but when I try Arabic characters it's not shown or shown not good.. so can anyone help it that?

Comment: What do you mean by "not good" ? Are there Arabic characters in your PDF but rendered left to right, or not with the font you specified ? or some non-Arabic glyphs that shouldn't be there ?

Comment: No i didn't mean the RTL support.. I meant the Arabic characters does not showing correctly they show something like that "þÿE1-(""

Comment: OK, so it's definitely an encoding issue. Have you looked at [existing issues on the jsPDF github](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+arabic+) ? there are actually quite a few titles concerning your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need add this line to document head section:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```